# Printing Precision of Machine Numbers

Tags: output-formatting, linux, machine-precision, mathematica-online

Is Mathematica making the print precision rounding judgment more stringent based on whether or not the number is above or below the rounding target? If so, why?

In my real case, I have many numbers on screen with about half of them represented with several zeros, and the other half with nothing after the decimal. That makes no sense to me.

I'm using [Mathematica Online](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/) if that is relevant.

```
$Version
(*11.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 2, 2017)*)
$CloudVersion
(*1.43.4 (September 12, 2017)*)
$MathematicaOnline
(*True*)
TableForm[Table[Join[{i,N[10^-i]},Flatten[{FullForm@#,#}&/@(11.0+{1,-1}*10^-i)]],
 {i,17}],TableHeadings->{None,{i,10^-i,11+10^-i,11+10^-i,11-10^-i,11-10^-i}}]
```

[image: Cloud Print Rounding]

Alexey has posted screenshots for Mathematica 8.0.4 and 11.2.0 on Windows, which I include below for comparison. Note the symmetrical rounding without the extra zeros. In my opinion, this is the original, intended, and correct behavior.

[image: Mathematica 8.0.4 Print Rounding on Windows]
[image: Mathematica 11.2.0 Print Rounding on Windows]

Comment: Here is what I get with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkVkk.png).

Comment: ... and with *Mathematica* 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64 the output is the same: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSCMI.png). So the issue is obviously platform-specific.

Comment: Would you be content with using `NumberForm` to control the number of digits?

Comment: @Chris Here are the screenshots: [version 8.0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFBXc.png), [version 11.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJFtE.png).